# Прерывание события при отпускании клавиши

Tags: c#, winforms, mediaplayer

Пишу пианино.
При нажатии на клавишу происходит событие Click, проигрывается звук.

```
 private void Form1_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
      { 
            switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.D1:
                if (!isPressed)
                {
                    isPressed = true;
                    button1.PerformClick();
                }
                label5.Text = "1";
                break;
         }
 private void Form1_KeyUp(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.D1: isPressed = false;
              break;
        }
   }
public void sound(string path)
    {
        var p1 = new MediaPlayer();
        p1.Open(new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative));
        p1.Play();
    }
private void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        s.sound(@"s//_1.wav");
        label3.Text = "До / 1";
    }
```

Вопрос: как прерывать воспроизведение звука ноты в зависимости при отпускании клавиши?
Допустим нажимаем и держим клавишу звук проигрывается полностью, при отпускание звук останавливается, при этом если одновременно нажимать на другие клавиши звук на всех кнопках будет проигрываться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если подходить обосновано сделайте так.
Во-первых, определяемся, какие звуки будут в нашем пианино

```
public enum SoundEnum 
{
   Do,
   Re,
   Mi
}
```

Создаем коллекцию звуков (при загрузке приложения)

```
private Dictionary<SoundEnum, MediaPlayer> sounds = new Dictionary<SoundEnum, MediaPlayer>();
```

Словарь состояния нажатия по всем клавишам (могу ошибиться с KeyCode, пишу не в IDE)

```
private Dictionary<KeyCode,bool> pressStates = new Dictionary<KeyCode,bool>();
```

В методе загрузки формы:

```
//Инициализируем словари
foreach(SoundEnum s in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SoundEnum)).Cast<SoundEnum>())
{
    sounds.Add(s, new MediaPlayer());
    pressStates.Add(s, false);
}
//Наполняем словарь звуками
sounds[SoundEnum.Do].Open(....);
sounds[SoundEnum.Re].Open(....);
```

Делаем функцию проигрывания звука

```
public void PlaySound(SoundEnum sound)
{
    sounds[sound].Play();
}
```

Делаем функцию прерывания звука

```
public void StopSound(SoundEnum sound)
{
    sounds[sound].Stop();
}
```

Словарь соответствия кнопок нотам

```
private Dictionary<KeyCode,SoundEnum> KeySounds = new Dictionary<KeyCode,SoundEnum>{{Keys.D1,SoundEnum.Do},...};
```

При нажатии делайте

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (!KeySounds.ContainsKey(e.KeyCode)) return;
    if (!pressStates[e.KeyCode])
    {
        pressStates[e.KeyCode] = true;
        PlaySound(KeySounds[e.KeyCode])
    {
}
```

При отпускании

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (!KeySounds.ContainsKey(e.KeyCode)) return;
    if (pressStates[e.KeyCode])
    {
        pressStates[e.KeyCode] = false;
        StopSound(KeySounds[e.KeyCode])
    {
}
```

Если еще есть кнопки на форме для мыши - тогда через события мыши для кнопок по аналогии.

Comment: Даже лучше делать не словарь состояний кнопок, а словарь состояний звуков - проигрывается или нет

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую, на KeyCode жалуется студия кстати

Comment: @Valentin ну я ж говорю, не в студии пишу, подставьте правильный тип

Comment: попробовал сделать, как вы описали выше, выдает ошибку: "Данный ключ отсутствует в словаре."

Comment: работают только клавиши от D1 до D0

Answer (score 3):

Для этого можно использовать события мыши для вашего контрола. Вам подойдут события `MouseUp` и `MouseDown`.Например в событии `MouseDown` можно прописать звучание клавиши, тогда она будет играть только при нажатой клавише мышки на контроле.Или в событии `MouseUp` прописать отмену проигрывания клавиши.

Привожу ссылки на официальную документацию в **msdn** по этим событиям

[MouseUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup(v=vs.110).aspx)
[MouseDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown(v=vs.110).aspx)